# How to apply gradient color on React Native StackedAreaChart?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg-charts

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts) library to make a `StackedAreaChart`. It's currently working but I need to change the colors to gradients. The examples provide in this package apply gradients only on `AreaChart`.

Here is my code

```
const hardCodedData = [
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 0, 1),
            apples: 3840,
            bananas: 1920,
            cherries: 960,
            dates: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 1, 1),
            apples: 1600,
            bananas: 1440,
            cherries: 960,
            dates: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 2, 1),
            apples: 640,
            bananas: 960,
            cherries: 3640,
            dates: 400,
        },
        {
            month: new Date(2015, 3, 1),
            apples: 3320,
            bananas: 480,
            cherries: 640,
            dates: 400,
        },
    ]

    const colors = ['#8800cc', '#aa00ff', '#cc66ff', '#eeccff']
    const keys = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries', 'dates']
    const svgs = [
        { onPress: () => alert('apples') },
        { onPress: () => alert('bananas') },
        { onPress: () => alert('cherries') },
        { onPress: () => alert('dates') },
    ]
<StackedAreaChart
   style={{ height: 200, paddingVertical: 16 }}
   data={hardCodedData}
   keys={keys}
   colors={colors}
   curve={shape.curveNatural}
   showGrid={false}
   svgs={svgs}
/>
```

Can you please provide me with some help in this ?

**EDIT**

```
const Gradient = () =>
        map(data, (d, i) => {
            let key = 'gradient' + d.id;
            let color = colors[d.id];

            return (
                <Defs key={key}>
                    <LinearGradient id={key} x1={'0'} y={'0%'} x2={'0'} y2={'100%'}>
                        <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor={color} />
                        <Stop
                            offset={'100%'}
                            stopColor={'red'}
                        />
                    </LinearGradient>
                </Defs>
            );
        });

    let fill1 = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;
    let fill2 = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;
    let fill3 = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;
    let fill4 = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;

    let gradients = [fill1, fill2, fill3, fill4]

 <StackedAreaChart
     style={{ height: 200, paddingVertical: 16 }}
     data={hardCodedData}
     keys={keys}
     colors={gradients}
     curve={shape.curveNatural}
     showGrid={false}
     svgs={svgs}
   >
     <Gradient />
   </StackedAreaChart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Gradient = () =>
map(data, (d, i) => {
  let key = 'gradient' + d.id;
  let color = Yourcolors[d.id];

  return (
    <Defs key={key}>
      <LinearGradient id={key} x1={'0'} y={'0%'} x2={'0'} y2={'100%'}>
        <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor={color} />
        <Stop
          offset={'100%'}
          stopColor={color2}
        />
      </LinearGradient>
    </Defs>
  );
});
...

<StackedAreaChart
   style={{ height: 200, paddingVertical: 16 }}
   data={hardCodedData}
   keys={keys}
   colors={gradients}
   curve={shape.curveNatural}
   showGrid={false}
   svgs={svgs}
>
<Gradient/>
</StackedAreaChart>
```

and in your colors just fill the areas with gradients like

```
let gradients = map(data, d=> {
  let fill = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;
return fill;
})

//this will generate an array of gradient defs
```

pass the gradients array instead of colors in your stackedareachart

PS. I have tested this type of implementation in other charts not in area chart

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am struggling to make it run, first I've got an error `can't find variable map` , and secondly `let fill = `url(#gradient${d.id})`;` , where should I declare this ? Because `d.id` would be undefined.

Comment: this is just for reference , you can import map from lodash and you need to generate the gradients array yourself according to your data.

Comment: just create a new array where you are creating colors array using map over your data

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I will update my question mate with the modified code, I got an error in fill1, fill2,... `can't find variable d`

Comment: check the answer now and make sure you have added id in your hardcodeddata

Comment: Thank you man , it's working but the result isn't satisfying, I will add an image in the question description. Hopefully you can help me with this

Comment: Thank you brother for your help, I found the issue , it was `d.id` that gives me the undefined key, I changed it to `d.month` in both Grandient and gradients map function.